# setting up a connection with PyMOL python

Tags: python, pymol

I have created a Contact Map using matplotlib in wxpython, now what i want to do is set up a 'connection' with pyMOL. i want my program to be like CM-View where when you hover over points on the contact map, it shows the 2 contacts on PyMOL showing a line between them. Also things like, telling pyMOL to only select 1 chain. 
So basically I want to send data from my GUI to pyMOL to make it do something, like the hovering over the contacts or telling pyMOL to do something.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not *Venkatramanan Krishnamani*, you may want to have a look of his code for a PyMOL extension [CMPyMOL](http://emptyewer.github.io/CMPyMOL/).

Hey, his extension/plugin is also for visualizing contact map!

In his plugin, the residues are not highlighted upon mouse hovering over contact map, rather mouse clicking on contact map. But that's close enough to what you want, I guess.